# How can I make the petals diamond shaped rather than an oval

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to use patterns to create a flower with diamond shaped petals but these oval shaped ones are the closest I've been able to get. I was wondering if anyone could help or provide any feed back with this.

Flower I'm trying to create

[image: Flower I'm trying to create]

Code:

```py
import turtle
def petal(t, r, angle):
    for i in range(2):
        t.circle(r,angle)
        t.left(180-angle)

def flower(t, n, r, angle):
    for i in range(n):
        petal(t,r,angle)
        t.left(360.0/n)

def move(t, length):
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("Yellow")
    t.pu()
    t.fd(length)
    t.pd()

sam = turtle.Turtle()

sam.speed(99)

move(sam, -150)

sam.color("red")
move(sam, 150)
flower(sam, 10, 40.0, 100.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use straight movements in the petal function:

```
def petal(t,d,a):
    for _ in range(2):
      t.fd(d)
      t.left(a)
      t.fd(d)
      t.left(180-a)
```

*note: the flower looks closer to your objective with an angle of 60 instead of 100*

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @AlainT. about the use of the smaller 60 degree angle, but I believe that solution falls short if we interpret `r` in the OP's `petal(t, r, angle)` call as *radius*.  If so, the rhombi drawn for the petals should be *constrained* by that radius:

[image]

To do so requires a little bit of math to calculate how far to move forward on each edge of the petal, not using the passed radius as the distance:

```
from math import radians, sin
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def petal(turtle, radius, angle):
    side = (radius / 2) / sin(radians(90 - angle/2))

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(side)
        turtle.left(angle)
        turtle.forward(side)
        turtle.left(180 - angle)

def flower(turtle, petals, radius, angle):

    for _ in range(petals):
        petal(turtle, radius, angle)
        turtle.left(360 / petals)

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('yellow')

sam = Turtle()
sam.hideturtle()
sam.speed('fastest')
sam.color('red')

flower(sam, 10, 80, 60)

screen.exitonclick()
```